# JavaScript concatenate arrays without duplication not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, concatenation

I have made a code in JavaScript to concatenate two arrays of names and sort them out without duplicate. When it shows on the screen I don't see the item 0 of my new array. I don't know why, in the console.log I see the item 0 which is "Alice". But, what I actually see on the webpage is 1. William, 2. Beatrice, 3. Charlie, 4. Charlotte, etc.

```js
let nameM = [
  "William",
  "Nathan",
  "Raphael",
  "Sam",
  "Emile",
  "Leo",
  "Pascal",
  "Felix"
];

let nameF = [
  "Charlotte",
  "Sam",
  "Emma",
  "Charlie",
  "Emilie",
  "Pascal",
  "Lea",
  "Beatrice",
  "Alice"
];

let name, list;
name = [];

function newArray(nameM, nameF) {
  nameM.concat(nameF).forEach(item => {
    if (name.indexOf(item) === -1)
      name.push(item);
  });
  return name;
}

console.log(newArray(nameM, nameF));

list = "<ol>";
name.forEach(firstName);
list += "</ol>";
document.getElementById("firstNames").innerHTML = list;

function firstName(values) {
  name.sort();
  list += "<li>" + values + "</li>";
}
```

Comment: 1) There seems to be no error also you can `concat` then like this: `const name = [...nameM, ...nameF]`  --- Simle and clean!

Comment: Like I said in the console.log everything seems to be fine, it's in the web page that i see the name "William" in first position and last position.

Comment: You're calling `sort()` every time you print a name. Don't do that. Call `sort()` once, before your call to `forEach`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks a lot! It was the thing that made appear the last name of the array on top of the other. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, use the [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to destructure the `nameM`  and `nameF` array. And add the destructured array in a `Set` to remove duplicates. Like this,

   ```
   const nameList = [...new Set([...nameM, ...nameF])];
   ```

2. Now because `nameList` is an array, we can chain methods on it. So to sort the array we can use the `.sort()` method on `nameList`.

   ```
   const nameList = [...new Set([...nameM, ...nameF])].sort()
   ```

3. At last we will chain another method `.forEach()` on sort. Select the `<ol>` element by id (`#firstNames`) and add the names to it using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

   ```
   const nameList = [...new Set([...nameM, ...nameF])]
     .sort()
     .forEach(
       (i) =>
       (document.getElementById("firstNames").innerHTML += `<li> ${i} </li>`)
     );
   ```

Finally, we get something like this:

```js
const nameM = [
  "William",
  "Nathan",
  "Raphael",
  "Sam",
  "Emile",
  "Leo",
  "Pascal",
  "Felix",
];

const nameF = [
  "Charlotte",
  "Sam",
  "Emma",
  "Charlie",
  "Emilie",
  "Pascal",
  "Lea",
  "Beatrice",
  "Alice",
];

const nameList = [...new Set([...nameM, ...nameF])]
  .sort()
  .forEach(
    (i) =>
    (document.getElementById("firstNames").innerHTML += `<li> ${i} </li>`)
  );
```

```html
<ol id="firstNames"></ol>
```

---

**Some useful resources:**

- [Destructuring assignment Documtation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Set Documtation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.sort() Documtation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Array.forEach() Documtation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Understanding Method Chaining In Javascript](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/understanding-method-chaining-in-javascript-647a9004bd4f)

Comment: Your output has duplicate `Sam`.

Comment: @Barmar I actually did not notice not to take duplicates, my bad . I have updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This can be «*simplified*» like this:

```js
let nameM = [
  "William",
  "Nathan",
  "Raphael",
  "Sam",
  "Emile",
  "Leo",
  "Pascal",
  "Felix"
];

let nameF = [
  "Charlotte",
  "Sam",
  "Emma",
  "Charlie",
  "Emilie",
  "Pascal",
  "Lea",
  "Beatrice",
  "Alice"
];

console.log(

[...nameM, ...nameF].sort()
  
)
```

Comment: What on earth is that sort key function doing?

Comment: It could be simplified even more with just `[...nameM, ...nameF].sort()`... No need for a nested ternary that does the same tests twice.